# how to make expo router keep the same page after devmode fast refresh

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-router

When we change something when using the expo router, the expo GO android app auto-refresh feature will redirect us to the first page. How can we make it keep the same route we were working on?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

`/app/_layout.js` is the first component that is rendered in my app. In that file, I use a `useEffect` hook to programmatically navigate to the page that I am working on after reload.

Example:

```
import { router } from 'expo-router'

useEffect(() => {
    router.navigate('/lessons/9e769435-cc94-4ba7-a506-a7d4b5d1eba2/exercises/6ba89021-96f3-4e04-955c-52c95f996ed9')
  }, []);
```